# Osmdroid -Tile Provider with higher zoom level

Tags: android, android-mapview, osmdroid, tile

I'm trying to implement a MapView using the osmdroid library, but the maximum zoom level is too low.
I've tried to change the tile source with the tiles provided by the TileSourceFactory class. All have the same maximum zoom level (18).

I would like to know if there is any Tile Provider that provides an higher zoom level and how I can use it in my application.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know osmdroid 4.0 provides max zoom level of 22.

Comment: @zIronManBox It is true, but MAPNICK (the default tile provider) offers 18 as higher zoom level. Is there any provider that offers an higher zoom level than 18?

Comment: developing map tiles provided by MAPNIK is 18max by MOBAC. You can make it stretchable using custom tools like Global Mapper.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to implement a regional map not the global map, you can edit it by yourself and put it into a zip archive. In this way I got zoom level 22 of my campus.

Set the max zoom level to 22:

```
mapView.setMaxZoomLevel(22);
```

Also set the max zoom level to 22 for online tile provider:

```
mapView.getTileProvider().setTileSource(new XYTileSource("Mapnik",
            0, 22, 256, ".png", new String[] {
            "http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/",
            "http://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/",
            "http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/" }));
```

This way can only achieve zoom level 22, and higher seems to be impossible. @zIronManBox said the max zoom level osmdroid supports is 22, but I didn't find where it declares. I appreciate if somebody could tell me.